# How to display values in table in jsp?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jstl

i am new to jsp and jstl i am working on this code to get the values from array using the for loop.i am getting the output, but i want to put that output into table.how to do this can anyone help me?

```
for ( int i =0; i < timeSize ; i++)
       {
         out.println(resource[i]);
         out.println(itimespend[i]);
         out.println(icostspend[i]);
         totalcost += itimespend[i] * icostspend[i];          
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not that difficult. The solution can be arrived at with an implementation like this :

```
<table>
<%
for ( int i =0; i < timeSize ; i++)
{
out.println(resource[i]);
out.println(itimespend[i]);
out.println(icostspend[i]);
totalcost += itimespend[i] * icostspend[i];     
%>

<tr>
<td> <%=resource[i]%></td>
<td><%=itimespend[i]%> </td>
<td> <%=icostspend[i]%></td>
</tr>

<%       
}
%>

</table>
```

Keep the table tag out side so as not to loop it every time and create a different table with every loop. This has not been tested, but I think you will get the basic idea from this one .

Answer (score 24):

client side, jsp

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Theme</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${themeList}" var="theme" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
            <td>${theme.id}</td>
            <td>${theme.theme}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

do not forget to declare the jstl taglib, and add the jstl libs to classpath

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

from server side you need to return a list to your jsp, something like this:

```
req.setAttribute("themeList", somelist);
```

but consider to use some MVC framework