# Showing table value in jsp

Tags: java

I am new to jsp servlet,I have one java file where with jdbc connection I am returing one table with two columns, now I want to display them in a jsp page with table format. Please help !

Comment: *I am returing one table with two columns* , What kind of Java data type is that ?

Comment: Add the `ResultSet` to a `List<Map>` , set it to the `request` or `session` attribute , Use **JSTL** to loop and **EL** to display , `<table><tr><td>`  format.

Comment: Possible duplicate question, check out this answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759149/how-to-display-values-in-table-in-jsp

Comment: @Kyle , The answer works, but bad coding style to use scriptlets.

Comment: did u write any code?

Comment: @NK123 not yet, I am going for what The New suggested

Comment: @DIP i have mention one tutorial link below in answer see this, you may get an idea how to deal with database and jsp and servlets.

Comment: @NK123 saw dt, its grt !

Answer (score 0):

you have to learn basics of servlet and JSP so read this tutorial [HERE](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/JSP-Servlet/13372-jsp-database-.html) try to run this code and then implement with your database table.

Answer (score -1):

```
request.setAttribute("colonne1", ListValueCol1);
request.setAttribute("colonne2", ListValueCol2);
```

and in your jsp:

```
<%
List<String> col1 = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("colonne1");
List<String> col2 = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("colonne2");
%>
```

and after that a loop to put the values in your table.