# Creating a JTable just gets to create a DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, javascript, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I'm new programming and I'm having many problems... I was just trying to create a JTable to export it afterwards to an excel. The code I'm using is:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import = "java.util.Properties"%>
<%@ page import = "java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page import = "java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import = "java.util.Iterator" %>

<%@ page import = "javax.swing.*" %>
<%@ page import = "java.awt.*" %>
<%@ page import = "javax.swing.table.*" %>
<%@ page import = "javax.swing.JScrollPane" %>

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(); 

        for(int col=1; col<=numberOfColumns; col++) 
        {
            columnName = rsMetaData.getColumnName(col);
            model.addColumn(columnName);
        }   
        while (rs.next())
        {
           Object [] fila = new Object[numberOfColumns]; 

           for (int i=0;i<numberOfColumns;i++) 
              fila[i] = rs.getObject(i+1); 

           model.addRow(fila); 
        }

        JTable tabla = new JTable(model);
```

If I bug the code I'm able to see that I have information in the different lines and columns, but nothing appears in tabla... I've been searching in several websites and it's the only structure I've found that I more or less undesrtood. In some of those webs kept going with the code with sentences like that:

```
JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(tabla);
```

but I'm not able to go further with the tabla problem...

Comment: Using Swing in JSP is meaningless, because Swing is for standalone clients while JSP is run on the server and the only thing the client gets is the text( usually http) output of the JSP. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759149/how-to-display-values-in-table-in-jsp for example how to create a table in JSP/HTML.

Comment: hey! thank you for taking some time to answer me! I've manage to create de HTML tables, but I need to export them to an excel. The different tables have to be in different worksheets in the same excel. That's why I tried to create a JTable... I found that it was the easiest way. I didn't manage to understand any code that would do that in HTML. Is there any way to export the HTML tables like that or do u have any idea of how could I do it? Thanx!!!! :D